# react-native: slow when navigating to screen for the first time

Tags: android, react-native

I am using react-native-navigation. I noticed that when navigating to a screen for the first time, the transition is somewhat choppy. But if I navigate to the screen again its smooth.

I assume the first time react-native is trying to load some resources? Maybe images and such?

I do my testing from an emulator but the issue is also present on a real device. If I navigate to my screens then reload the app(dev mode) everything is smooth.

Comment: I don't think this is supposed to happen. Do you 'Debug Remotely'? If so, when you turn that off, the issue should go away on a real device

Comment: No. Compiling the app and installing on my device does not get rid of the issue. Like I said it's on the first run only. When I open a modal the first time it's a bit slow. Second time is smooth. Some screens behave the same way. First navigation is a tad slow. Smooth on second run